# How to populate data to an array?

Tags: typescript

im new in ts and i have an issue with populating data to an array. Im reading csv file using type, in parse function i use createData method which creates an object of CSVData and then pushes it to an array. I read csv and can log data into console but im not sure why this data doesnt push into an array.

```
export class CSVData {
private firstName: string;
private lastName: string;
private gender: string;


constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string, gender: string) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.gender = gender;
 }
```

}

```
readData(): CSVData[] {
    const csvFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../test-file.csv');
    const headers = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'gender'];
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(csvFilePath, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
    const data: CSVData[] = [];

    parse(fileContent, {
        delimiter: ',',
        from_line: 2,
        columns: headers,
    },
        (error, result: DataType[]) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
            this.createData(data, result);
        });
    return data;
};

 createData(newData: CSVData[], data: DataType[]): void {
    console.log(data.length);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let dataObj: CSVData = new CSVData(data[i].first_name, data[i].last_name, data[i].gender);
        newData.push(dataObj);
    }

}
```

when i run `console.log(readData())` it shows me an empty array

UPDATE:
im using parse from csv-parse library:

```
const { parse } = require("csv-parse");
```

Comment: You don't show how `parse` is implemented, but it seems to take a callback, possibly suggesting that the actual push to the array might be happening asynchronously and the array isn't populated at the point you return from the method?

Comment: @Paddy parse is from this package:  const { parse } = require("csv-parse");

Answer (score 1):

This is due to `parse` function is `asynchronous`

To fix this you can update the parse function call with a `promise` and `await` it.

Which will then return the parsed values.

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
parse(fileContent, {
  delimiter: ',',
  from_line: 2,
  columns: headers,
}, (error, result: DataType[]) => {
  if (error) {
    reject(error);
  } else {
    createData(data, result);
    resolve();
  }
});
```

});